# How do you stretch and center item using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Take a look at this https://codepen.io/techsin/pen/JWQgoM

```
//html
<div class="nav"> a \ b \ c</div>
<div class="box"> no text</div>

//css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.box {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-grow:1; 
}


.nav {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

I want box to expand like a block element, but not expand beyond max width, and still be centered.

If I set `align-items` to stretch on body then box do expands but it gets aligned to left, if set margin auto Or align-items to center, then box stops trying to fill as much as possible width wise.

I simply want box to expand to 800 pixels, but when windows size changes its width also goes down, just like how any regular block element's width would act by default.

Whole reason to use flexbox is to have box also cover remaining height.

Comment: its working in same way, I can't see any problem.

Comment: i want box to expand vertically to fill up remaining space, also expand horizontally but not more than 800px and reduce in size when screen width is shorter, and stay centered horizontally. Right now that's not the case. It does expand vertically, but it either expands to 800px or it's  centered, not both at the same time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give the `box` `width: 100%;`, `margin: 0 auto;` and `box-sizing: border-box;`, so the padding gets included in its width

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWgXYN)

Stack snippet

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav {
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: purple;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav"> a \ b \ c</div>
<div class="box"> no text</div>
```

Comment: so whole trick is to add `width: 100%`, i learned something today

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Basically yes